# Unable to install ubuntu 13.04 on HP p2-1334 desktop PC(preinstalled windows 8) - Blank screen/hang

Tags: installation, dual-boot, grub2

Problem: [I get a text mode menu from GRUB that ask me if I want to install, After selecting to Install, the screen goes black-blank and lastly PC hangs, no more actions or noises]

Steps I've done:

Bios changes:
- Boot order (to make it boot from a CD or USB drive)
- Secure boot option disabled

Result [Fail]

From Windows 8
Accessed Change PC settings
Selected to restart from a CD or USB drive > Advance settings option
Fast Start Up Disable

Result [Fail]

Comment: I suggest having a look here to explain about EUFI and how to get Ubuntu installed: [Impossible installing Ubuntu 13.04 in UEFI mode with Windows 8 preinstalled](http://askubuntu.com/questions/299671/impossible-installing-ubuntu-13-04-in-uefi-mode-with-windows-8-preinstalled)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try pressing F12(maybe another key for your BIOS) to enable dialogue that asks from which drive would you like to boot up ?