# Cannot boot WUBI installed Ubuntu with Windows 8

Tags: wubi, windows-8, uefi

I installed Ubuntu on Samsung laptop with Windows 8, everything went fine but on booting with Ubuntu I get the following message:

```
\ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr
status 0xc000007b
The application or operating system cold not be loaded because a required file is missing or contains errors.
```

Any solutions? I also cannot boot from USB.

Comment: You are likely dealing with UEFI and SecureBoot.  See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/206950/12-10-uefi-secure-boot-install

Comment: Are you using **12.04 LTS** or **12.10** Ubuntu?

Comment: Using 12.04 LTS

Comment: Please indicate your Boot-Info URL ( https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info ).