# Boot manager is showing \Ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr is missing or contains error

Tags: boot, wubi, secure-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed UEFI Supported Windows 8 system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 version using windows installer option along with windows 8. After selecting Ubuntu during boot option, boot manager is showing the below error message.

"The os couldn't be loaded because the file \Ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr is missing or contains error"

Kindly help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Try to scan your disk for errors in windows. Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/206950/12-10-uefi-secure-boot-install (possible duplicate?)

Comment: Wubi doesn't work on computers with UEFI boot. You need to do a normal dual boot. http://pad.lv/694242

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem on an HP Pavilion G6-2240sa preloaded with Windows8.  It turned out that for some reason that key files on the DVD I burned on the same machine were not recognized at boot time. The solution in the end was to create a USB stick boot drive  by downloading the data from the Ubuntu site and creating the bootable drive using the software site recommended by the Ubuntu site  ["How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows"](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).  Do not just copy the files to the USB drive.  I also had to edit the BIOS to look for the bootable USB drive before booting from the internal hard disk. If you would like more details with a blow-by-blow account [see here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227149/how-do-i-install-12-10-on-a-pavilion-g6-laptop-with-uefi/227329#227329)

Answer (score -1):

Did you install Windows after Ubuntu,if that so then use boot repair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair . this is a really great tool. You just have to boot ubuntu through live cd and select try ubuntu and follow instruction given in above link.

Comment: On wubi installs, boot repair replaces the windows bootloader, resets the boot flag (on the same partition), and fscks the root.disk. Neither of these will help in this case.