# Install problem on UEFI, Windows 8 new desktop

Tags: system-installation, windows-8, uefi

I just bought an HP desktop, p6-2326s, which has windows 8 installed.  I have tried booting a Ubuntu live disc but the machine won't boot it.  When I bring up the UEFI boot menu it offers a selection of UEFI BOOT SOURCES, windows boot manager, dvd drive, IP4 Ethernet controller, or IP6 Ethernet controller.  If I select the dvd drive with the CD in it I get the message
"Secure boot violation,  Invalid structure detected.  Check secure boot policy in setup."  With all other selections it just boots into windows.
So where do I go from here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Answer (score 0):

Disable secure boot in your bios. This will prevent the system from preventing you from running the installer. In the future, versions of GNU/Linux (including Ubuntu) will have workarounds for this feature. For now, complain to Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Ubuntu have you tried ?

I think Ubuntu 12.10 64bit supports UEFI mode and secure boot out of the box.

Here is a similar question-answer : [12.10 UEFI Secure Boot install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206950/12-10-uefi-secure-boot-install)

Answer (score 0):

1. With SecureBoot enabled computers, you need to use `Ubuntu-Secure-Remix-64bit` (or `Ubuntu12.10 64bit`)
2. If the error persists, disable SecureBoot in your firmware as described here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#SecureBoot , and try again.
3. Once you can boot the Ubuntu disk, install Ubuntu and use Boot-Repair's `Recommended Repair` as described in the first paragraph of https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI