# Ubuntu 12.10 and dual Boot with Windows 8 uefi on Sony VAIO SVS1512

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, uefi, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [12.10 UEFI Secure Boot install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206950/12-10-uefi-secure-boot-install)

I've spent the whole day trying to get windows 8 to dual boot with ubuntu on my Sony Vaio SVS1512Z9EB. I tried boot-repair as mentioned in many other threads but it still only boots Windows 8. You can view my URL [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1409149/)
Is there anything to do to get the dual boot? thanks

Comment: use only 64bit edition of ubuntu. 32bit version isn't supported. If you are still facing the issue you can try disabling secure boot.

Comment: Actually I'm using kubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64. I hope it makes no difference? My bios is set in UEFI mode and I disabled the secure boot. I run again the boot-repair, after restart windows-8 still boot automatically! My new URL is [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1409861). What about the note I get from boot-repair, that I have to make the Bios boot on sda1/EFI/ubuntu/grub64.efi file ?

Comment: I followed the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI). I also checked that everything is booting/running in EFI mode.

Comment: See http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12386053&postcount=653 . So please wait that all packages have the **green check** on this page: https://launchpad.net/~yannubuntu/+archive/boot-repair/+packages , then update and run Boot-Repair's `Recommended Repair`.

Comment: This is ***NOT*** a duplicate with the referenced question. Albatross is almost certainly running into problems related to a buggy Sony UEFI implementation. See http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=117497&p=653175, and in particular the posts by louisgv and responses by srs5694 (that's me on that forum), for information on this problem.

Comment: Thank u a lot! It works now. The last update of boot-repair did it. My last note: I kept the the Secure-Boot disabled.