# Can't get to Grub (UEFI) on Sony VAIO Ubuntu 15.04 Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, uefi, sony

Okay. I've been trying to get GRUB to load for a long time (bordering on two years of attempts). I have windows 7 on a Sony VAIO (`SVS151190X`) and I am attempting to boot Ubuntu 15.04 through GRUB, but I can't get to GRUB...

This post is an overall *extension of details* of a similar/same problem posted in: https://askubuntu.com/questions/666690/cannot-boot-ubuntu-15-04-using-sony-vaio-with-win-8-1-pre-installed

Things I've Tried:

1. Use easyBCD (yes, I realized it only works with MBR based systems so
   I undid everything I did with that
2. Use `bcdedit` command in cmd in windows to change the path of `{bootmgr}` to `/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi` that didn't work, I ran boot-repair and used it to ONLY reinstall grub and then I went back to windows and change the path of `{bootmgr}` to `/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi` and still no success. Then I reset `{bootmgr}`'s path to the original windows path (`/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi`).
3. Then, I tried what was mentioned in other articles: **replacing the bootmgfw.efi with the grubx64.efi file**, but *that did not work*. There were many other efi boot files (ones for UEFI boot as stated in grub.cfg, which I used as a reference to figure out what some files did) in `/EFI/Microsoft` and `/EFI/Boot`. I replaced *every single one with grubx64.efi* (renamed of course). For each replacement I renamed the windows file from `file.efi` to `file.win.efi`.

By the way, I attempted to directly edit grub.cfg (carefully, using the files I was supposed to edit as reference, in addition to searching the file for all references to bootmgfw.efi. I only edited the list, and specifically the path when I renamed the windows files; nothing else (except right below the list where it has a path for one of the windows things). Now, the reason I had to do this was because `sudo grub-update` returned: 
`/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of /cow.`
This occurred after installing boot-repair in a live session, since before I install it boot-repair is just an unknown command...BUT then I tried it again right now in this live session (after `sudo apt-get install grub`) and it worked fine and I made sure the windows paths were set correctly, but that is not important until I actually gain access to grub.

Also, my BIOS only contains the options of booting off the internal HDD, external device, disk drive, or network. There are no *options of selecting windows or Ubuntu, just HDD*.

I've viewed so many help pages, including:

- [How to fix dual-booting Windows 8 and Ubuntu 14.04 on a Sony Vaio?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458413/how-to-fix-dual-booting-windows-8-and-ubuntu-14-04-on-a-sony-vaio/)
- [Ubuntu 12.10 and dual Boot with Windows 8 uefi on Sony VAIO SVS1512](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225192/ubuntu-12-10-and-dual-boot-with-windows-8-uefi-on-sony-vaio-svs1512)
- [How to understand Ubuntu UEFI Secure Boot install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206950/how-to-understand-ubuntu-uefi-secure-boot-install)
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Laptop/Sony/Vaio/Duo11/Trusty
- [How to fix dual-booting Windows 8 and Ubuntu 14.04 on a Sony Vaio?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458413/how-to-fix-dual-booting-windows-8-and-ubuntu-14-04-on-a-sony-vaio)
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2227580
- And many, many more that I can't remember

So, has anyone successfully dual booted Ubuntu with Windows, after the things I listed above did not work for you and you found a solution that did?

Help is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Edit: To clarify, Ubuntu is installed and so is the grub boot loader, I just can't manage to arrive at the grub boot loader when I boot my laptop.

Comment: What do you mean you can't get into? Can you install Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu has been installed for a while, its grub that I can't access, I am sent straight to the Windows boot loader where I can select only Windows 7. I need access to grub, which I have been unable to do.

Comment: Post link to the Create BootInfo summary report.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info You may  have changed so much that a total uninstall/reinstall of grub using Boot-Repair would help. Usually the copy of grub or shim and rename to /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi works, but then Windows updates overwrite it. The copy of all of /EFI/ubuntu to /EFI/Boot and rename shimx64.efi to bootx64.efi is preferred. The shim or grub in /EFI/Boot still reads the copy of grub.cfg in /EFI/ubuntu so do not modify it. That grub.cfg is just a configfile (chain load) to real grub.cfg in your install.

Comment: @oldfred Here is the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12775253/

I tried copying shimx64.efi around those different directories, but the windows boot manager continued to show up.

Comment: Try this: `sudo efibootmgr -c -g -d /dev/sdX -p Y -w -L "UEFI: Hard Drive Boot" -l "\EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi"`  
sdX is drive, Y is efi partition. yours is sda3. Details on each parameter. http://linux.die.net/man/8/efibootmgr

Comment: @oldfred I just tried that (twice) and when I turned my laptop on it just did the usual, then I booted to my USB drive and checked efibootmgr and it had reset to what it had said before I added the new item. And shimx64.efi is the file in place of bootx64.efi, correct? (That's how I have it)

Comment: That should be correct if you changed to correct X & Y and yes you want shim as bootx64.efi.  If still not working, then try Rod Smith's rEFInd, I have not yet used it, but it is another work around for UEFI that are difficult. http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/  Have you updated UEFI from Sony to latest version?Vendors also have many fixes, some not listed that are needed.

Comment: I believe X and Y were changed correctly, since efibootmgr showed the proper results (Y was 3 since /sda3 is the EFI partition and X was a for drive /sda). I believe my UEFI is up-to-date (the update on the product page was released 2 months before systeminfo shows the original install date of windows, leading me to assume the UEFI is up to date, I of course could also check the version but I can't do that at the moment). I will look into rEFInd and possibly try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many Sonys have cruddy firmware (EFIs) that refuse to launch anything but the Windows boot manager -- that is, `EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi`. The only workaround I know of is to replace that file with GRUB (or, if Secure Boot is active, with Shim, with GRUB stored in its normal filename in the `EFI/Microsoft/Boot` directory). The [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) program can do this automatically, but you must enter the Advanced menu and select the appropriate option, which is called something like "back up and replace boot files" (I don't recall the precise wording).

Another thing you might try is replacing the stock Windows installation with a fresh install from retail (not OEM) disks. See [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/186775/how-to-download-windows-7-8-and-8.1-installation-media-legally/) for information on how to obtain various Windows installation media legally. The point of this procedure is to remove the manufacturer-specific cruft that infests most computers and that can add an extra layer of complexity to the boot process.

The most radical solution is to re-install everything in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, bypassing EFI-mode booting. The limitations in the Sony apply to EFI mode only, so a BIOS-mode boot should bypass these problems; however, such a conversion would be tricky to carry out without a full re-install, and even with a re-install, there will be problems. See [my page on CSM issues](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) for details.

I know you say you've tried much of this and it hasn't worked. Unfortunately, your problem is that you've got a defective computer. If you hadn't had it for so long, I'd suggest you return it to the store for a refund, but I doubt if they'd take it back after two years.

Comment: I've actually had it for 4 years haha, but thanks for the response. I'll be getting a new computer before college probably, so I'll probably just have to wait a few months. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have managed to get to GRUB on a Vaio SVS1511T9ES. It was a long dance, with many weird steps, and obviously may or may not work for you (or any future readers), but posting here just in case it helps someone:

[Dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 + Windows 7 UEFI — GRUB menu doesn't appear](https://askubuntu.com/q/1054861/111779)

Answer (score 0):

My situation after replacing the HD:

1. Using UEFI + Secure Boot
2. Installed Windows 10
3. Installed Ubuntu 19.04

System is booting into Windows each time. No sign of Grub. In fact even going into Windows and select 'Advanced Boot Options' and 'Ubuntu' boots into Windows.

Based on previous hard won experience with this machine (Sony Vaio S1513Z9E/B) the only way to get EFI to boot anything but Windows is to replace the file /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi.

Note that I have tried replace the boot record, also BCDEdit, to no avail.

Step 1. Replace bootmgfw.efi

1. Boot into Windows 10
2. run 'diskpart'
3. execute 'list disk'
4. select the boot disk, e.g. 'sel disk 0'
5. execute 'list vol'
6. select the EFI volume, e.g. 'sel vol 2'
7. Assign a free drive letter, e.g. 'assign letter=E:'

The Windows boot manager now have to be renamed and replaced by the Ubuntu 'shim64x' boot manager. This example apply to UEFI + secure boot only!

1. cd /d E:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\
2. move bootmgfw.efi bootmgfw_org.efi
3. copy E:\EFI\ubuntu*.efi
4. copy shimx64.efi bootmgfw.efi

From E:\EFI\ubuntu\ at least shimx64.efi and grubx64.efi will be needed.

Now reboot the computer. It should boot into Grub. Grub have the menu alternatives Ubuntu and Windows 10. By choosing 'Ubuntu' it will boot Ubuntu, as expected.

There is a problem with the entry for Windows. It is still pointing to bootmgfw.efi, that will falsely boot Ubuntu.

In order to create a grub entry that correctly load Windows, proceed as follows.

1. Find the blkid of the EFI partition, e.g. 'sudo blkid /dev/sda2' (sda2 would be the EFI partition.
2. You will need the value of the UUID field (not the PARTUUID).
3. Edit /etc/grub.d/40_custom to add the following entry, 
   `menuentry "Windows 10 UEFI" --class windows --class os {
       insmod ntfs
       search --no-floppy --set=root --fs-uuid D604-55F0
       chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw_org.efi
   }`
4. An alternative entry, same function. `menuentry "Windows 10 UEFI" {
       search --set=root --fs-uuid D604-55F0 --file /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw_org.efi
       chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw_org.efi
   }`
5. Recreate grub config, e.g. 'sudo update-grub'.

After this the grub menu entry 'Ubuntu' will boot Ubuntu. The menu entry 'Windows 10 UEFI' will boot Windows 10.

Note that the 'bootmgfw_org.efi' refered to above is the original renamed Windows boot manager. It hat to be done this way since the Vaio refuse to boot any other file. Attempts to edit/reconfigure BCD to make it boot Ubuntu as intended by UEFI specification have failed.