# Boot Repair failed, what should I do

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

This is the pastebin result: https://paste.ubuntu.com/15009157/

I also got this message from the report but I don't know how to proceed with this. Can someone please explain this:

> The boot files of [The OS now in use - Ubuntu 15.10] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of the disk). This can be performed via tools such as gParted. Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot partition:] option of [Boot Repair]. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)

Comment: Have you tried turning off secure boot in UEFI? Are you booting in UEFI mode? As you also have grub installed for BIOS boot, but system is UEFI.  The message on far from start of disk is for older IDE systems or perhaps full installs on USB flash drives. Have not seen the issue on any newer UEFI system. So you can ignore that issue. What brand/model system. Some only like to boot Windows and need additional work arounds.

Comment: I have just turned secure boot off. My laptop only runs in UEFI but Legacy usually doesn't. It came with Windows 8.1 but I uninstalled that and I'm fully on Ubuntu. I had this same problem when I first got 14.04 but I don't remember how I solved it. It's Acer Aspire E5-511-P95S.

Comment: Acer's require supervisory password & setting "trust" on Ubuntu's efi boot files. Have you done that? http://askubuntu.com/questions/597213/bootable-device-not-found-after-clean-install-of-ubuntu-14-04-uefi and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/597213/bootable-device-not-found-after-clean-install-of-ubuntu-14-04-uefi/653202#653202

Comment: You could try entering your firmware setup utility, selecting the option to reset the firmware settings to their defaults, removing *all files* from `/dev/sda1`, and then re-running Boot Repair. If that doesn't work, and if the computer is new enough, return it for a refund and get another because it's defective. If that's not an option, there's an ugly workaround involving renaming boot files. See my answer to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/685021/cant-get-to-grub-uefi-on-sony-vaio-ubuntu-15-04-dual-boot) for more on this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall Ubuntu GRUB boot loader.
Boot from the Ubuntu installation media.

Select Try Ubuntu without installing.
On desktop open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub
```

Note : `sda` = disk | `sda1` = efi partition | `sda2` = system partition

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it didn't work.