# Installing on windows 8

Tags: installation, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [12.10 UEFI Secure Boot install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206950/12-10-uefi-secure-boot-install)
>   [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed UEFI Supported Windows 8 system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

When ever I try to boot from a dvd for 12.10, an error messages shows that says that the system was unable to boot windows.  This laptop is a dell insipron 15x, it came installed with windows 8, is there any one who has had this problem before and can help.

Comment: Maybe you have to turn out «Secure Boot» (at the bottom of this manual: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that you are not booting from Ubuntu. I'm not sure why Windows is complaining that you have a boot disk for Ubuntu, however.

To boot from Ubuntu, when you first start up your computer, there is something called a BIOS. This is the first screen you see when you start your computer; it should show a Dell logo (as you are on a Dell Inspiron). There, you should see text say "Press F for more boot options" or something like that. On the top of your keyboard you should have those F-Keys, or function keys. Press the corresponding key, and you should be lead to a window where you can select which volume you should boot from. Select the correct one, and Ubuntu will boot.

Comment: Re previous answer - I have a Dell Inspiron 1545 and the key to press when the Dell Logo appears at boot up is F12. You should see various boot options - top will be HDD - Boot from DVD should be further down the list. Click on that.