# Do I have to partition the drive in windows before installing Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

Very quick and simple question but just want to make sure before I go ahead and install. I understand that Ubuntu 12.04.2 comes with the necessary keys to install alongside windows 8 with UEFI and Secureboot.

My question is can I just install via CD from boot and choose install alongside windows and choose partition size  in this setup or do I have to partition the drive in windows before installing Ubuntu?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed UEFI Supported Windows 8 system](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

Comment: thanks for the help, though i read this http://askubuntu.com/questions/206950/12-10-uefi-secure-boot-install which led me to believe that 12.04.2 had they keys for secure boot? am i misinterpreting?

Comment: also this resource http://www.pcworld.com/article/2028388/two-ubuntu-linux-versions-can-now-work-with-secure-boot.html

Answer (score 0):

I would use the advanced partitioning tool in the installer, it works.

!!! Warning: If for some reason Ubuntu doesn't recognize Windows, do **not** try to partition it. This will ruin your data !!!

As far as I remember, the 64-bit version recognizes UEFI, but 32-bit doesn't.

Comment: its ok im using 64bit,so the something else option?

Comment: should work. If it doesn't, Look at this:http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to use the WINDOWS partition manager to create the empty space in which to install Ubuntu. Apparently GPartex doesn't see windows partitions in some circumstances.