# Installation Issue: No Option To Install

Tags: system-installation, uefi, hardware

I got a new computer (HP Envy h8-1534) pre-installed with Windows 8, and came across an interesting issue while attempting to install Ubuntu.

So, as I install, I don't get that slide asking whether or not I want to install side by side with another operating system, wipe the entire disk, or make my own configuration.

I get this slide instead:

[image: http://postimg.org/image/4qgq74wb5/]

<sup>Click on the image to see a full-resolution version.</sup>

If I push anything, it then gives me the message: "Ubuntu has experienced an internal error."

I then tried using an Ubuntu 12.04.2 disk that worked fine for me in the past, and got exactly the same problem.

Comment: Does the hard drive is it ok?

Comment: Yes, the computer is brand new, and Windows 8 boots up fine.

Comment: I'm using the 64 bit version, Radu.

Comment: Two possible reasons: 1. The computer came with 4 primary partitions, the maximum allowed. 2. The computer has a small SSD used as cache that Ubuntu views as RAID0 and can't use.

Comment: Looks like your HDD is not being recognized, check your BIOS to see what configuration is available for your HDD.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to understand Ubuntu UEFI Secure Boot install?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206950/how-to-understand-ubuntu-uefi-secure-boot-install)